# Write $(12)(13)(23)(142)$ as the product of disjoint cycles.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles

I got that

$$(12)(13)(23)(142) = (14)(2314) = (234)$$

I am thinking that this is incorrect, but I am unsure how to fix my work. Can someone tell me if this is the correct approach?

Thanks!

Comment: I got $(1423)$. Id est, we got one cycle.

Comment: The only tricky part is which order of composition an author chooses.  Most authors will specify that permutations are applied from left to right, but some will use right to left.  So check the text to be sure you are consistent in applying this cycle notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align}
1&\stackrel{(142)}{\mapsto}4\stackrel{(23)}{\mapsto}4\stackrel{(13)}{\mapsto}4\stackrel{(12)}{\mapsto}4, \\
2&\stackrel{(142)}{\mapsto}1\stackrel{(23)}{\mapsto}1\stackrel{(13)}{\mapsto}3\stackrel{(12)}{\mapsto}3, \\
3&\stackrel{(142)}{\mapsto}3\stackrel{(23)}{\mapsto}2\stackrel{(13)}{\mapsto}2\stackrel{(12)}{\mapsto}1, \\
4&\stackrel{(142)}{\mapsto}2\stackrel{(23)}{\mapsto}3\stackrel{(13)}{\mapsto}1\stackrel{(12)}{\mapsto}2, 
\end{align}$$ so the product is $(1423)$.

Answer (score 1):

$(12)(13)(23)(142)=(1423)$, just by checking where each element goes.